# java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is already initialized. Even though work manager is not initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager, workmanagers

I am trying to do custom work manager initialisation. I do not want the work manager to get initialised at the beginning, I want to initialise only if login is success. But I always get the below exception even though work manager is not initialised:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is already initialized.  Did you try to initialize it manually without disabling WorkManagerInitializer? See WorkManager#initialize(Context, Configuration) or the class level Javadoc for more information.
```

Below is my manifest file, I have disabled default initialisation of work manager:

```
 <provider
            tools:node="remove"
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
            android:exported="false"
            android:enabled="false"/>
```

Below is my application class, I have implemented Configuration.Provider:

```
open class MyApplication : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
 daggerComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().application(this).build()
    
}

  override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration(): Configuration {
        val factory: AppWorkerFactory = daggerComponent?.factory()!!
       return Configuration.Builder()
            .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.INFO)
            .setExecutor(appExecutors.upload).setWorkerFactory(factory)
            .build()
    }
}
```

I am trying to initialise the work manager as shown below in LoginFragment if login is success:

```
WorkManager.initialize(activity?.application as MyApplication, (activity?.application as MyApplication).workManagerConfiguration)
```

Please let me know what am I missing and why am I not able to initialise work manager in Login Fragment, I have not initialised work manager in any other place, but still why am I getting work manager already initialised exception?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/55875560/3159267

Comment: @rajan.kali I have tried that, in the custom class I am not sure how we can get access to application class to initialize factory

Comment: I have added an answer to access your application class inside content provider

Comment: Why are you manually calling `initialize` when you're overriding `getWorkManagerConfiguration()` to provide your configuration for automatic initialization?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I felt its mandatory to call initialise since its mentioned in docs is it not needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are implementing [On Demand Initialization](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/custom-configuration#on-demand) by having your application implement `Configuration.Provider` and override `getWorkManagerConfiguration()`, then you **do not** need to call `initialize` manually - that's precisely what On Deman Initialization is doing for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `context.applicationContext` in `ContentProvider` to get hold of `Application` class as in

```
class WorkManagerInit : ContentProvider {
    override fun onCreate() : Boolean{
        context?.let {
            val myApp = context.applicationContext as MyApplication
            WorkManager.initialize(myApp, myApp.getWorkManagerConfiguration())
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this I am getting null pointer when I try to access work manager configuration ` Caused by: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at .MyApplication.getWorkManagerConfiguration`

Comment: You can use method instead of variable I guess, check the updated answer