# ProcessLifecycleOwner is not giving lifecycle callback in Application class

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-lifecycle, android-workmanager

I am using `ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().lifecycle.addObserver(this)` in my Application class, and I expected to get `onStateChanged()` callback to be called, however I have added a provider in my manifest for disabling the standard automated initialisation of WorkManager.

```
 <provider
  android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
  android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
  tools:node="remove">
 </provider>
```

From couple of other solutions listed in SO, I have modified the provider as follows

And I can see the first `onStateChanged()` callback with event `ON_CREATE` and immediately the app crashes. and the crash log is given below

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is already initialized.  Did you try to initialize it manually without disabling WorkManagerInitializer`

Does anyone has worked on such thing, suggest any working approaches ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I have created another package `androix/lifecycle` and added a new class and initialised the `ProcessLifeCycleOwner` as follows

```
fun initialize(context: Application): LifecycleOwner {
        LifecycleDispatcher.init(context)
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.init(context)
        return ProcessLifecycleOwner.get()
    }
```

And that worked perfect

Answer (score 2):

`WorkManager` and `ProcessLifecycleOwner` both use `androidx.startup`. To disable the default initializer for `WorkManager` without disabling `androidx.startup` altogether, use this:

```
 <provider
    android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:node="merge">
    <!-- If you are using androidx.startup to initialize other components -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:value="androidx.startup"
        tools:node="remove" />
 </provider>
```

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/configuration/custom-configuration#remove-default)

Answer (score 0):

You probably already have a Workermanager initialized in the Android manifest.

```
<!-- disable default provider -->
           <provider
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
            tools:node="remove" />
```

REF:[Custom initialization of Workmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69028255/13533028)

Comment: Yes, I am disabling the workmanager auto initialisation in manifest as mentioned in the question, cant we handle it together in anyway ? @Narendra_Nath